# Reading In Data From A Text File And Separating Out The Data Contained In Each Line

Tags: c++, string, io, ifstream

In the program currently I wish to read in text from a text file line by line, extracting data from each line. Each line in the text file contains a letter such as “A” followed by a colon “:” followed by an integer such as “2”. The function in the program that should read in the data currently looks like this:

```
void readFile()
{
std::ifstream aFile;                                                                                                                                                                                
std::string alldata;
std::string letter;                                                                                                                 
aFile.open("KeyPopularity.txt");
while (std::getline(aFile, alldata))
{                                                                                                           
    letter = alldata[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < keyboardKeys.size(); i++)
    {
        if (keyboardKeys[i].character==letter)                                                                                      
        {
            keyboardKeys[i].noOfPresses = int(alldata[2]);                                                                          
        }
        std::cout << letter << " ";
        std::cout << int(alldata[2]) << "\n";
    }
}
aFile.clear();                                                                                                                      
}
```

However the alldata variable at position 0 (alldata[0]) instead of listing just a single character ie the letter lists a number such as 87 before the letter eg. 87 W as opposed to just W. The question is why is this happening and is there a way to extract the data from each line in the text file line by line to obtain the letter at position 0 of a line string and the number at position 2 of the line string?

Answer (score 1):

Some observation/mistakes in your program:

- letter is a std::string, however you assign a character to it; this is allowed but are you sure that this is the intent? You can use char instead of string.
- alldata[2] is a char. For the line "A:2" for example, the value will be '2' (with ascii value 50, which is not the same as value 2). You cannot simply convert it to int with int(). To convert a character of a digit ('0'..'9') to its respective integer value you need to subtract the value 48 from the ascii code (or '0').
- also change type of keyboardKeys[i].character to char instead of std::string

You can rewrite your code like this:

```
void readFile()
{
    std::ifstream aFile;
    std::string alldata;
    char letter;
    aFile.open("KeyPopularity.txt");
    while (std::getline(aFile, alldata))
    {
        letter = alldata[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < keyboardKeys.size(); i++)
        {
            if (keyboardKeys[i].character == letter)
            {
                keyboardKeys[i].noOfPresses = alldata[2] - '0';
            }
            std::cout << letter << " ";
            std::cout << alldata[2] - '0' << "\n";
        }
    }
    aFile.clear();
}
```

Comment: One more observation: if the number of presses read from the file is greater than 9, then the above code won't work, since it reads only the first digit.
        
        You can adapt the code so it strips the first two characters from alldata (so the key and the ':'), you can do that with alldata.erase(0, 2)
        
        Then you can convert the resulting string to an integer, with keyboardKeys[i].noOfPresses = stoi(alldata); However stoi is available only in C++11, for older c++ you can use the good old [atol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atol/) from stdlib.h